# What's a good replacement font for ITC Avant Garde Std?

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation, free

I have a PSD comp for a website and the titles are in [ITC Avant Garde Std](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1768). What's a good replacement font? It should be available for the web, either free or on TypeKit.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Century Gothic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Gothic) is pretty well-saturated on the Web and has letterforms that are in the same ballpark as Avant Garde. If a Mac doesn't have it on their system, you can put Futura lower down the font stack.

Not sure how scientific these surveys are, but the numbers are in line with what I've read before: Century Gothic is on probably about [87% of PCs](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-WindowsResults.shtml) (63% of Macs too!) and Futura is on about [96% of Macs](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-MacResults.shtml).

Comment: Century Gothic looks standard on Windows, but not Mac. But there is Futura PT on TypeKit! Sweet.

Comment: @ageektrapped Updated my answer to show some stats. Not sure how reliable the numbers are but it seemed about right.

Answer (score 16):

Tex Gyre Adventor is a really nice replacement for both Avant Garde and Century Gothic. Useful if you also target devices that are not a pc or Mac. It's available as a @font-face kit at [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com): http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/TeX-Gyre-Adventor

[image]

Comment: So... it's a copy of "URW Gothic", which is itself a copy of ITC Avant Garde?  :-/

Comment: 'Good artists copy, great artists steal' - Pablo Picasso

Comment: @user568458 I think it's not a *copy* of **URW Gothic L**; it's an *extension* of it. See: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87hagen-gyre.pdf and http://typophile.com/node/41012

Comment: Fantastic. I'm about to replace some Avant Garde GIFs on my website with webfonts.

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is a bit old, but I faced this issue today and finally found a GoogleFont alternative : [Poppins](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins)

[image]

Beside some letter width and the letter Q (which is completely different), the font is a pretty good and free alternative.

Comment: This should clearly be the accepted updated answer

Answer (score 7):

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway

"Raleway" from google webfonts is very close and easy to use.

[image]

Comment: Nice find - also, check out the alternate glyphs at http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/raleway for more Avant Garde like `a`s, `l`s, `w`s and `t`s (editted in an image).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, if the ascenders on Futura PT are too crazy high, or if someone finding this is looking for a free alternative to ITC Avant Garde, [Didact Gothic on Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Didact+Gothic) has many features in common.

The capitals are less eyecatching than Avant Garde's, and the letters are more uniform (e.g. no crazy-slim `r`), but it has a similar clear clean simplicity. It's probably suitable for use in titles or large, short (bullet list?) text.

It's got a decent range of glyphs, but unfortunately only one weight (standard/400), so it's not a good replacement for the elegant light or heavy Avant Garde weights.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Questrial is pretty close but only available in Regular:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Questrial

[image: Questrial Regular]

Comment: it's actually quite different (G/Q/R/j/w/&/numbers), can you explain why you think this is a good replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Publica Sans from Facetype It has even more glyphs and stylistic alternates than ITC Avante Garde Gothic. http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/facetype/publica-sans/

Comment: Please do not only give a link anser, please add here an image to show that font could be a solution ... Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

DIN Schriften Neuzeit Grotesk Light would be a good replacement. You can use [IdentiFont](http://www.identifont.com/) to locate similar fonts.

Comment: can you just add a screenshot of the font so we don't have to go hunting for it?

Answer (score 0):

And even another answer! ;)

Wikipedia states that

> [...] an **AvantGarde clone** known as "Gothic L". It (or a derivative) is used by much open-source software such as R as a system font.

They mean the font developed by the URW team, so here you have
[URW Gotic L](https://www.azfonts.net/families/urw-gothic-l.html)