# What Fonts Complement Walkway?

Tags: website-design, fonts

I'm using [Walkway **bold**](http://www.dafont.com/walkway.font) on a project, and am looking for some nice fonts for the titles. Walkway is sort of formal and stylistic to me, and nostalgic of the 1920's. I'm looking for fonts that go well with it for a crowd funding website.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, that is a rather poor typeface just in terms of mechanicals and overall balance. I'd suggest finding something else. Regardless, asking what fonts compliment another is going to produces a lot of subjective suggestions...not the best question for StackExchange.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to use Walkway for body text [bad idea, but never mind] and are looking for titles. You'd be better off doing it the other way round; in either case you would need a geometric serif font. [Rockwell](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/rockwell/) might work or possibly [Nexa Slab](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/nexa-slab/); but the choice is entirely subjective.

Comment: For a font that's "formal and stylistic to me, and nostalgic of the 1920's" (so classic and slightly unobtrusively art deco?) and suitable for body text (i.e. high readability), browsing [fonts similar to Avant Garde](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/) might be a good place to start. A font like Walkway can work in short snippets like headings, but the uneven letter spacing might make it tiring and effortful to read long paragraphs of it.

Comment: Disagree with the close votes. There are fonts you can recommend using established design and typographic principles. They've been discussed on this site before.

Comment: @Brendan it's not that you can't have an answer, it's that there is no 'right' answer.

Comment: I don't like using Walkway for body text at all, but that's what my client has been sold on, and tasked me with. Rather than trying to manipulate my client, I thought I'd just take the challenge, sort of regretfully. But the suggestions were great and very helpful -thank you. Market Deco is going to work well. The body text is only a paragraph on the Home page--not pages upon pages of it, thankfully.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think [Market Deco](http://www.dafont.com/market-deco.font) would be nice but if you need lower case letters, I think [Blue Highway](http://www.dafont.com/blue-highway.font) would look fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's somewhat subjective, of course, but I'd say these are too similar to be paired well with Walkway (they also suffer the same sloppy mechanicals, unfortunately)

Comment: I agree with DA01, my opinion would be that Walkway should be used for titles and then something like Microsoft JhengHei (found in Photoshop) for the body.